# How to find the line of action of the net force resulting from a horizontal and vertical force acting at two different centers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, torque

For a homework question, I have to find the hydrostatic forces on a floodgate, which is inclined at 60 deg from the horizontal, at the end of a pipe. I have solved for the vertical (4,444 N) and horizontal (1,1545 N) forces and their respective centers of pressure, which are at different points down the gate (0.67m and 0.62m down the gate, respectively). But, I don't know how to find the center the combined force acts upon.

I can find the magnitude of the overall force through vector addition (12,371 N) and I can find the torque acting (6,254 Nm, which would be equivalent to 9,621 N acting 0.65m down the gate, taking the weighted average), but that only takes into account the components of the force perpendicular to the gate.

I believe I'm supposed to use moments to solve this part of the problem, but it's a water engineering course which assumes we know all this basic stuff, and I don't have the same background/knowledge as the rest of the students. Are moments different to torque?

[image]

Comment: Moments and torque are the same. ... Pressure acts perpendicular to the plate, so you do not need to find vertical and horizontal components. (General result : total force on plate = area of plate x pressure at the centroid of the plate.) For calculation of centre of pressure see [here](http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/aerothermal_dvd_only/aero/fprops/statics/node20.html) or [here](https://www.sfu.ca/~mbahrami/ENSC%20283/Lab/Center%20of%20Pressure%20and%20Hydrostatic%20Force%20on%20a%20submerged%20body-Rev.pdf).